# PDO named prepared statements not worked

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement, firebird

Strange behavior with Firebird through PDO.

**Environment:**

- On my local machine(Ubuntu 12.04) all works correctly.
- On remote machine (old Mandriva [kernel 2.6.33.7-server-2mnb])
      only unnamed PDO statements worked...
- php5.3.14 on both
- Firebird 2.5 on both

When I tell *not worked*, I mean:

- `SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username = ?` with `array($username)` - worked
- `SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username = :u` with `array(':u' => $username)` - not

(worked = returns a user with username field equals to $username value)

**Questions:**

- Have anybody experience with this behavior?
- Where should I looking for `pdo` versions? 
    (I have only *PDO Driver for Firebird/InterBase  enabled* in my phpinfo)

Thanks

**Here is my test code:**

```
$user = 'alex';
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true);
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username = :u';
$st = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$st->execute(array(':u' => $user));
$rows = $st->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($rows);
```

Comment: Post the code, not some sketch

Comment: Does PDO::setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true); has any effect over this?

Comment: `When I tell not worked, I mean` - you should mean what particularly doesn't work, explaining it in details, instead of using just one three-letter word "not".

Comment: `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` does not change anything

Comment: @YourCommonSense, ok just moment

Comment: guy, which downvoted, add your comment why, please

Comment: Are you sure that everything from the Firebird and PHP versions and configurations to the code and database contents are identical? Maybe it has to do something with character encodings. Have you tried copying the configurations and dumping the database over? Just to be sure.

Comment: @Ivarpoiss: database content identical, it works even when I connect to remote firebird from local machine... Encodings... I use utf8 everywhere...

Comment: What errors does PDO report?

Comment: no errors, empty array, no data

Comment: you don't need to set PDO::PARAM_NULL manually as PDO will set it automatically in case value is null. At least it works this way for other drivers.

Comment: Try to update your PHP to a more recent version

Comment: I can't ;( php 5.2 was here. I discussed long time, and get this php version... I can't get more recent...

Comment: I can't to understand why my home 5.3.10 works properly...

Comment: @YourCommonSense, mean you more recent build? I can't to get 5.4, but 5.3 can... Mean you 5.3.28?

Comment: 5.3 is unsupported version already. And recent is 5.5

Comment: I think your latest update should be posted as a separate question from the original question. Or maybe a bug report to PHP.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Bug report obviously won't be accepted as he would be asked to upgrade his ancient version first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve a problem, it was with Mandriva package sources:

`urpmi` on a remote system has been configured to some local source of 2010 year
Blame on our admin)
I remove this source, reinstall php and pdo from remote package source, and all works now!
I'm happy :)

Thanks to all